# How to bypass Touch ID provided access to the iCloud account?

Tags: icloud, password, touch-id

If a user has Touch ID on. Then he loses his finger, or dies. How to unlock the phone? Provided he or his family know the iCloud password.

Comment: Do you know the phone password?

Comment: @JBis yes. I know it.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have the **iPhone password** you can unlock the iPhone.

Without the **iPhone password** (or the finger...) (even if you have the Apple ID password) you will not be able gain access to the phone. You can however wipe the phone and use the Apple ID to unlock the phone from [Activation Lock](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201365).

Since you have both you can you can [wipe the phone](https://support.apple.com/en-us/ht201274) and start from new.

Answer (score 0):

An iCloud account does not grant local access to a device. Only Touch ID or the device passcode can open the device.

If iCloud Backup was enabled on the device and a backup was taken, then the iCloud account can be used to restore this backup to a new device which will give you access to the data.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea. We'll try it. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Follow this step by step tutorial

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ui1u0MZW_HQ
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cap0lxqYrEE
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lqYfhv1-UkE
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l1R_tCRDj8I

https://xdarom.com/icloud-activation-bypass-tool/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different and thank you for your answer. :) Unfortunately, short answers such as this don't really provide enough detail or context to help many users. And, just providing links isn't very helpful as they may no longer work in future. Instead, could you please edit your answer (there's an _edit_ link below it) to include a summary of the content you're linking to? This will make your answer more self-contained and help preserve it for other users in future.

Answer (score -2):

Since Touch ID password is stored on local device. And every device is allowed to enabled for 10 finger by default, it is recommended to have one of the family member for enabling of Touch ID. But if iOS device passcode is aware, then in that case will be able to login into iOS device and add new finger for enabling Touch ID.